# ORMLite Null ForeignCollection within ForeignCollection

Tags: android, ormlite

I have Entity A, Entity B, and Entity C. Entity A has a foreign collection of Entity B and a reference to the currently selected B, and B has a foreign collection of Entity C. Each entity has a reference back to it's parent.

```
//A
@DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_SELECTED_B,
        foreign = true,
        foreignAutoRefresh = true,
        maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel = 3)
private B selectedB;

@ForeignCollectionField(columnName = COLUMN_BS,
        eager = true,
        maxEagerLevel = 3)
private ForeignCollection<GoalWeek> bs;


//B
@ForeignCollectionField(columnName = COLUMN_CS,
        maxEagerLevel = 2,
        eager = true)
private ForeignCollection<C> cs;
```

I create object A, and then I later pull it from the db. I then instantiate an object B, add it to the collection of A, and set the variable "selectedB" inside a to that as well. I then update A and B.

Later on when I pull object A, the selectedB is eagerly loaded. But when I try to add an object C to the collection of Cs inside of B, the collection of Cs is ALWAYS null.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** If I load entity A, then get the id of the selected B, and load it, everything works as expected, but this is a huge hassle. Surely there is a way to make this work just by loading A.

Comment: Any feedback on my answer.  Please accept it if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does the object C has a reference to the object B?

Every "collection-stored" object has to have a reference to the object that puts it in a collection, or ORMLite cannot load it automagically.

Comment: Yes it does. If I do a get of the Object B, the collection of Object C, won't be null, but if I get Object A, it is. The collection of C may be empty, but it's not null.

Answer (score 0):

> I create object A, and then I later pull it from the db. I then instantiate an object B, add it to the collection of A, and set the variable "selectedB" inside a to that as well. I then update A and B.

If I am understanding this question, if you load `A` from the database, the collection of `B`s inside of `A` looks good.  However, the collection of `C` entities within each `B` in the collection is null.  Right?

I think you need to increase the [`@ForeignCollectionField(maxEagerLevel = ...)` value](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/ForeignCollectionField.html#maxEagerLevel%28%29).  By default when you get `A`, the eager collection of `B`s is hydrated but not `B`s eager collections.  The decision was made to do this so the objects didn't go recursive and didn't generate a ton of database requests.

By increasing the `maxEagerLevel` value, ORMLite will recursively load the sub-collections.  To quote from javadocs:

> Set this to be the number of times to expand an eager foreign collection's foreign collection. If you query for A and it has an eager foreign-collection of field B which has an eager foreign-collection of field C ..., then a lot of database operations are going to happen whenever you query for A. By default this value is 1 meaning that if you query for A, the collection of B will be eager fetched but each of the B objects will have a lazy collection instead of an eager collection of C. It should be increased only if you know what you are doing.

Comment: I tried that. The current value is 3 which should work. Just to be sure though I increased it to 5. No such luck.

Comment: @Gray From my experience, if I do `Dao.setObjectCache(true);` `ForeignCollection` can sometimes become null. If I set it to `false` it is never null.

Comment: Can you post a question to the mailing list @dzeikei.  That's just not enough information to diagnose the issue.  If you can provide a junit test that fails, that would help immensely.

Comment: @Gray I'll see if I can package something up in the weekend. BTW this is on Android.